# Crash on CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this code:

```
    NSURL *pdfURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
  pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
  CFRelease(pdfURL);
```

'path' is just an NSString path the the file I am loading from the documents directory. I have chanced to ensure the path is correct. I am also running on the simulator but I don't see why this should make a difference in this situation.

Any ideas why the crash is occurring?

Thanks

Comment: If `path` is a local file-system path, then you should use `fileURLWithPath:`, not `URLWithString:` (which specifically takes a *URL* string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't release pdfURL. URLWithString: returns an autoreleased object.